# eh.js and eh.css in IIS log

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

I just deployed a new MVC 4 web application and have been keeping an eye on the IIS logs to make sure everything is running smoothly. I noticed that some user's browser's request two files that do not exist in my project and I have no idea what they are: eh.js & eh.css. These two files are not part of my project and I don't know why they are being requested from the server, IIS returns 404. Has anyone else ran into this? Can anyone tell me what eh.js & eh.css are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I feel sheepish, eh.js and eh.css are resources on my organization's error page.